# PHP script exec bash script does not print all bash lines

Tags: php, bash, exec

I have php script on my redhat that im logging in as root via telnet client.
My PHP script to run the bash script is(functions.inc):

```
<?php
exec('/ilantest/testscript.sh');
?>
```

My Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"
echo "Whats going on ?"
```

And when i do: php functions.inc - I get the following:
Whats going on ?[root@X ilantest]#

Why i dont see the first line ?
Thanks !

Comment: what is that 'e' doing after first echo statement ?

Comment: sorry, there is no "e" fixed the Q.. + when i ./testscript.sh it works ok and print the 2 lines

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Perl-output to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407590/return-perl-output-to-php)

Comment: this is the original, maybe the other one is duplicate of this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#refsect1-function.exec-returnvalues

> The **last** line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a
> command and have all the data from the command passed directly back
> without any interference, use the passthru() function. To get the
> output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the **output**
> **parameter**.

So:

```
exec('/ilantest/testscript.sh', $output);
echo implode("\n", $output);
```

Comment: Or better to use another function, that return output always.

Comment: @gaRex, of course OP would want to check the return value of the script, and make sure $output is not empty before doing implode(), but that all depends on how OP codes the shell script.

Comment: then it's even may be better to use proc_* functions stack.

Comment: This is incorrect. "output" is an array of each line, not a string.

Comment: @kainjow ok....hence the use of `implode()` to convert the array to a string. I don't understand what you are trying to refute.

Comment: @crypticツ oops, completely misread that. My bad, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

In your php script try

```
echo system('/ilantest/testscript.sh');
```

Comment: ok all string with \n (!), but repeat the last one... using `shell_exec()` instead system, not cause side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

Only the last line will be printed if you don't specify any arguments to receive the output. From [**exec()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) manual:

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be
>   filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing
>   whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if
>   the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the
>   end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements,
>   call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().

You can pass an array to receive all lines:

```
<?php
$lines = array();
exec('/ilantest/testscript.sh', $lines);
foreach($lines as $i) {
    echo $i;
}
?>
```